# How do I extract a Postgres timestamp field using java?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

My data is in format:

2010-12-01 09:59:00.423

getDate in Java only returns the date portion. Is there a way to also extract the time?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The SQL `DATE` type indeed only contains the date portion, not the time. But your column is apparently of `TIMESTAMP` type, so to get the full timestamp, use [`ResultSet#getTimestamp()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int%29) instead.

```
Date date = resultSet.getTimestamp("columnname");
// ...
```

It returns [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) which is a subclass of [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), so the upcast is safe.